# Angular 5 wait for multiple child notifications

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, angular2-observables

I have a parent component that includes two child components.  Each of the children has their own network load, and I need to know in the parent component when both children are done with their network loads.  I had assumed I could use an observable for this but it didn't work for me.  In both my child components I did this:

```js
private _loadFinished = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
loadFinished = this._loadFinished.asObservable();

networkLoad() {
   this.network.doLoad().subscribe(x => {
       this._loadFinished.next(true);
   });
}
```

In the parent's HTML, I tagged each child component and then in the code I did this:

```js
@ViewChild('orgMetrics') orgMetrics: ChildComponentOne;
@ViewChild('campusMetrics') campusMetrics: ChildComponentTwo;

loading = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(
        this.orgMetrics.loadFinished,
        this.campusMetrics.loadFinished
    ).subscribe(() => {
        console.info("I got here");
        this.loading = false;
    }, () => this.loading = false);
}
```

}

The `subscribe` is never getting hit though.  Am I going the completely wrong direction here?  I was also looking at en `EventEmitter` but I didn't understand how I would wait for both to be done before taking action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) function will emit only when the given Observables have *completed*. i.e., it will not emit when the Observables you give it simply *emit* values of their own.

Because you are using [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject), calling `this._loadFinished.next(true)` will only emit a single value from the Observable, and it will not complete.

A quick fix is to simply call `_loadFinished.complete()` after emitting the one and only value:

```
networkLoad() {
   this.network.doLoad().subscribe(x => {
       this._loadFinished.next(true);
       this._loadFinished.complete();
   });
}
```

If you had some reason to keep the BehaviorSubjects around, you might also find the [Observable.combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) operator more appropriate, as it simply looks for the latest emitted values from an Observable.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing '@ViewChild('orgMetrics')' component inside ngOnInit(). But the correct way is using ngAfterViewInit(). Another way is, declare the BehaviorSubject Observable and Observer inside service and access through component.

**Service:**

```
private _loadFinished = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
loadFinished = this._loadFinished.asObservable();
private _loadFinished1 = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
loadFinished1 = this._loadFinished1.asObservable();

load1Finished(){ //call this method from child component
  this.loadFinished.next(true);
}

load2Finished(){ //call this method from child component
  this.loadFinished1.next(true);
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
loading = true;

ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(
        this.Service.loadFinished,
        this.Service.loadFinished1
    ).subscribe(() => {
        console.info("I got here");
        this.loading = false;
    }, () => this.loading = false);
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, how about adding a comment why so we can all learn from it?

Comment: Thanks.  I moved my stuff into a service to be cleaner, and then added the `complete()` call that was reference in the post I marked as the answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it usin [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

**Parent:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.html'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  onChanges(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

**Parent Html:**

```
<app-child (valueChange)="onChanges($event)"></app-child>
```

**Child:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.html'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

  networkFinished() {
    this.valueChange.emit('child1');
  }
}
```

**[Here is a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-sharing-data-child-to-parent?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent.ts)**

Comment: That works for a single item, yes, but the question was specifically around multiple child events being emitted.

Comment: You can set a variable by Parent as 0 and when each child has finished make this variable ++,  when it equals children length then all have finished.